# Birthday Inequality for non uniform distribution with specific collision entropy

Tags: co.combinatorics, probability-distributions

Let $D$ be a distribution with collision-entropy $k$, i.e.,  $H_2(D) = k$. 
Let $n$ samples are chosen independently according to the distribution $D$. Let $E_n$ be the event that there is no collision among the $n$ samples. We are interested in a non trivial upper bound for the probability of the event $E_n$. i.e., $Pr[E_n] \le ?$ or how many samples are needed so that the chance of one collision is at least 1/2?

Comment: This is now answered in http://mathoverflow.net/a/257340/101775

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Birthday inequality for non-uniform distributions for fixed collision probability (random allocation, collision probability)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/257027/birthday-inequality-for-non-uniform-distributions-for-fixed-collision-probabilit)