# Birthday problem for non-uniform probabilities

Tags: pr.probability

Consider [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) generalization to non-uniform day probabilities:

Draw $k$ IID samples from multinomial distribution $\mathcal{P}$ over $d$ outcomes, $n=1$ trials and outcome probability vector $\mathbf{p}$
$$\mathbf{p}=p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_d$$

Let $s_1,\ldots,s_k$ represent $k$ IID draws from $\mathcal{P}$.
What is the smallest $k$ such that the probability of having a collision in $s_1,\ldots,s_k$ is at least 50%?

$s_1,\ldots,s_k$ is considered to have a collision iff $\exists m>n$ such that $s_m=s_n$

In numerical simulations, the following appears to be a good fit
$$k\approx \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2\|\mathbf{p}\|^2}}$$
Why?

The formula looks equivalent to Robert Israel's [formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348365/expected-number-of-drawings-to-find-collision/1348408#1348408) of numbers of draws until collision where $R=\frac{1}{\|\mathbf{p}\|^2}$ plays the role of $d$

---

Here's the [simulation](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-birthday-problem.nb), I take distributions of the form $p_i=c_1 i^{c_2}$ with varying $c_2$ and plot the smallest group size at which half the trials get a collision against the value of $R=\frac{1}{\|\mathbf{p}\|^2}$.

[image]

([crossposted](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/614754/birthday-paradox-for-non-uniform-probabilities) on crossvalidated.SE)

Comment: What do you mean by "the same class"?

Comment: I mean -- "landing in the same bucket", where you have $d$ buckets with corresponding probabilities $p_1,\ldots,p_d$ and sampling IID with replacement

Comment: Can you just give a formal statement of the problem, without buckets, classes, etc.?

Comment: It also looks like your "multinomial" distribution corresponds to just one trial ($n=1$ on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution)).

Comment: When the $p_j$'s are all the same, the constant factor is, not $\sqrt{\pi/2}=1.253\dots$, but $\sqrt{2\ln2}=1.177\dots$.

Comment: Updated [simulation](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-birthday-problem.nb) post with $\sqrt{2 \log 2}$ graph. One issue is that it was derived for $d\to \infty$ whereas my simulation is for $d=200$

Comment: This latest plot suggests that the "constant" factor may depend on the underlying distribution.

Comment: Is there an explanation for the $\sqrt{R}$ factor?

Comment: Yes, that explanation is easy.

Comment: more general, related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263368/birthday-problem-with-unequal-probability-expected-number-of-draws-before-the

Comment: You may have simulated the mean time to the first collision, rather than what you said you wanted to estimate: "the smallest $k$ such that the probability of having a collision in $s_1,\ldots,s_k$ is at least 50%".

Comment: @IosifPinelis I don't think so, the code computes collision counts for all lengths up to "maxLength", then computes empirical collision probabilities for all length. I'll rerun using more efficient code to make sure it gives the $\sqrt{2\log 2}$ constant for larger $d$

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov : I have not read your code in detail, but I have noticed "given probability distribution h, estimate mean time to first collision" there. Also, $\sqrt{\pi/2}$ is the [constant factor for that mean time](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263368/birthday-problem-with-unequal-probability-expected-number-of-draws-before-the). This explains my last comment above. Anyhow, what do you think about my answer?

Comment: @IosifPinelis thanks, the answer makes sense. My motivation for this question is listing simple criteria $R$ which capture the concept of "high-dimensional" for non-isotropic distributions. As $R\to\infty$, many things become exactly true (perhaps like this [one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444091/when-is-prod-i-0-infty-i-x-i-x-it-0-for-zero-centered-gaussian-x-i)). To this end, I'm curious why your condition 30 uses effective days defined as $\|\mathbf{p}\|^2/p^2_\text{max}$. Could we not instead define effective days more simply as $1/\|\mathbf{p}\|^2$ and require that to be large?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov : You latter comment is now addressed at the end of my answer. Please let me know if you have further concerns.

Comment: @IosifPinelis this addresses the question, thanks. Regarding your earlier comment about shape of distribution affecting results, I've performed [simulations](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-mean-time-to-collision.nb) on a wide variety of examples for related "mean-time until collision" problem and observed that $\sqrt{\pi R/2}$ appears to be a non-asymptotic lower-bound, while upper bound appears to be achieved by $p_1=\beta$ distribution described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4635453/998)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov : Thank you for this further comment.

Comment: @IosifPinelis btw, added a a few more simulations [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2917025). Plotting "mean time to collision" for probability distributions obtained from normalized spectra of 300 famous graphs, it's almost always larger than "mean time to collision for a uniform dist in $d=R$ dimensions, I wonder if there's a better statistic than $R$ to capture this

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov : Thank you for your comment. I will have it in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\PP}{\mathcal P}\newcommand{\np}{\|\mathbf p\|}\newcommand{\pmax}{p_{\max}}\newcommand{\X}[2]{X_{\{#1,#2\}}}\newcommand{\sub}[3]{#1_{\{#2,#3\}}}\newcommand{\Ga}{\Gamma}\newcommand\la\lambda$The correct constant factor is, not $\sqrt{\pi/2}=1.253\ldots$, but
\begin{equation*}
    c_*:=\sqrt{2\ln2}=1.177\ldots. \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}

Indeed, let $Y_1,\dots,Y_d$ be independent random variables (r.v.'s) such that $P(Y_a=j)=p_j$ for all $a\in[k]:=\{1,\dots,k\}$ and $j\in[d]$. Let $\PP_k$ denote the set of all subsets of $[k]$ of cardinality $2$. For each set $\{a,b\}\in\PP_k$, let
\begin{equation*}
    \X ab:=1(Y_a=Y_b). 
\end{equation*}
Let
\begin{equation*}
    \np:=\sqrt{\sum_{j\in[d]}p_j^2}\quad\text{and}\quad \pmax:=\max_{j\in[d]}p_j. 
\end{equation*}
Let
\begin{equation*}
    P_k:=P(S_k=0),\quad\text{where}\quad S_k:=\sum_{\{a,b\}\in\PP_k}\X ab. \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation*}

> **Theorem 1.** If
> \begin{equation*}
>     \np\to0, \tag{25}\label{25}
> \end{equation*}
> \begin{equation*}
>     \pmax=o(\np), \tag{30}\label{30}
> \end{equation*}
> and
> \begin{equation*}
>     k\sim\frac c\np \tag{40}\label{40}
> \end{equation*}
> for some real $c>0$, then
> \begin{equation*}
>     P_k\to e^{-c^2/2}. \tag{50}\label{50}
> \end{equation*}
> In particular, if $c=c_*$ (with $c_*$ as in \eqref{10}), then
> \begin{equation*}
>     P_k\to1/2. 
> \end{equation*}

*Remark:* Condition \eqref{30} means that the effective number, $\np^2/\pmax^2$, of "calendar dates" in this non-uniform version of the birthday "paradox" is large. In particular, if $p_1=\cdots=p_d=1/d$, then this effective number of "calendar dates" is $d$, the actual number of "calendar dates" in the usual, uniform version of the birthday "paradox".

*Remark:* The probability $P_k$ can be interpreted as the probability of not having the same birthday for any two of the $k$ i.i.d. individuals given that, for each $j\in[d]$, the probability of a birthday on day $j$ is $p_j$.

---

The proof of Theorem 1 is a direct application of a result on Stein's method for Poisson approximation. Such an application is possible because the random indicators $\X ab$ are almost independent.
Specifically, in [Theorem 2.5 on p.70](https://www.google.com/books/edition/An_Introduction_to_Stein_s_Method/iK9sPXG7A6EC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=The%20local%20approach), let $\Ga:=\PP_k$,
$\sub\Ga ab^s:=\{\{c,d\}\in\Ga\colon|\{c,d\}\cap\{a,b\}|=1\}$, and
$\sub\Ga ab^w:=\{\{c,d\}\in\Ga\colon|\{c,d\}\cap\{a,b\}|=0\}$, where $|\cdot|$ denotes the cardinality.

Note that for each $i\in\Ga$ we have $EX_i=\np^2=E(X_i|W_i)$ (since $X_i$ is independent of $W_i=\sum_{j\in\Ga_i^w}X_j$) and hence
\begin{equation*}
    \la=\binom k2\np^2\sim k^2\np^2/2\to c^2/2;  \tag{60}\label{60}
\end{equation*}
$EZ_i\le2k\np^2$; and $EX_iZ_i\le2k\np^2\pmax$. Also, $k_2(\la)\le1$ (and also $k_1(\la)\le1$, but in this case $k_1(\la)$ will get multiplied by $0$ anyway). We thus conclude that
\begin{equation*}
    |P_k-e^{-\la}|\le\frac{k^2}2\,(\np^2(\np^2+2k\np^2)+2k\np^2\pmax)\to0,
\end{equation*}
in view of the conditions \eqref{25}, \eqref{30}, and \eqref{40}. So, in view of \eqref{60}, we get \eqref{50}. $\quad\Box$

---

Relation \eqref{50} is illustrated in this [Mathematica notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/ipinelis/Published/NonUniformBirthdayParadox.nb). At the end of the notebook, one can see graphs $\{(c,\tilde P_k/e^{-c^2/2})\colon c\in\frac{c_*}5\,\{1,\dots,10\}\}$ for simulated values $\tilde P_k$ of $P_k$, $p_j=j/\sum_{i\in[d]}i$ for $j\in d$, $k=\lceil c/\np\rceil$, $d=500$ with $1000$ simulations (penultimate graph), and $d=1000$ with $2000$ simulations (last graph). We see good agreement with \eqref{50} for values of $c$ around and/or to the left of $c_*$, but this agreement seems worse for larger values of $c$ -- which may be caused by relatively small values of the limit probability $e^{-c^2/2}$, which is therefore harder to simulate.

---

**Added:** A result more general than Theorem 1 above is [Theorem 4](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/electronic-journal-of-probability/volume-5/issue-none/Limit-Distributions-and-Random-Trees-Derived-from-the-Birthday-Problem/10.1214/EJP.v5-58.full) by Camarri and Pitman, which states the following (in terms of the present answer):

> Suppose that $\pmax\to0$ (which of course implies $d\to\infty$ and is equivalent to \eqref{25}).
> Suppose also that
> for each $j=1,2,\dots$ and some $t_j$ we have
> \begin{equation}
>     p_j/\np\to t_j. \tag{70}\label{70}
> \end{equation}
> (So, necessarily $t_j\in[0,1]$ for all $j$.) Then, for $k$ as in \eqref{40},
> \begin{equation*}
>     P_k\to Q(c):=e^{-c^2(1-\sum_j t_j^2)/2}\prod_j(1+t_j c)e^{-t_j c}. \tag{80}\label{80}
> \end{equation*}
> Moreover, condition \eqref{70} is necessary for $P_k$ to converge for all real $c>0$.

(Thanks to [kodlu](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446149/birthday-problem-for-non-uniform-probabilities/446167#comment1152394_446167) for the [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263368/birthday-problem-with-unequal-probability-expected-number-of-draws-before-the) to a question containing a reference to the paper by Camarri and Pitman.)

Clearly, Theorem 1 in this answer is a special case of the just stated theorem by Camarri and  Pitman: specifically, our Theorem 1 corresponds to the case when $t_j=0$ for all $j$. However, the proof of Theorem 1 presented above seems much simpler than the proof of the theorem by Camarri and Pitman. Also, the equation $e^{-c^2/2}=1/2$ is much easier to solve (to get the solution $c=c_*$ as in \eqref{10}) than the equation $Q(c)=1/2$ in general, with $Q(c)$ as defined in \eqref{80}.

Comment: more general, related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263368/birthday-problem-with-unequal-probability-expected-number-of-draws-before-the

Comment: @kodlu : Thank you for your comment. I did suspect that this result should be known, and (at least to me) this is a case when it is easier to prove a result than to find it in the literature.

Comment: yes, your answer is nice, and of course the $\ell_2$ norm of the probability vector is the collision probability and is related to the Renyi entropy of order 2 which comes up in some cryptographic brute force computations

Comment: @kodlu : Thank you for your further comment.